# Помогите установить Django 3

Tags: python, django, pip, python-3.9

Получаю такую ошибку

```
pip install -U Django==3
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==3 (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14, 1.11.15, 1.11.16, 1.11.17, 1.11.18, 1.11.20, 1.11.21, 1.11.22, 1.11.23, 1.11.24, 1.11.25, 1.11.26, 1.11.27, 1.11.28, 1.11.29, 2.0a1, 2.0b1, 2.0rc1, 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.0.10, 2.0.12, 2.0.13, 2.1a1, 2.1b1, 2.1rc1, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.1.10, 2.1.11, 2.1.12, 2.1.13, 2.1.14, 2.1.15, 2.2a1, 2.2b1, 2.2rc1, 2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.2.6, 2.2.7, 2.2.8, 2.2.9, 2.2.10, 2.2.11, 2.2.12, 2.2.13, 2.2.14, 2.2.15, 2.2.16, 2.2.17)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Django==3
```

Comment: Какая у вас версия питона?

Comment: обновил до 3.9.

Comment: А pip точно именно от версии 3.9?

Comment: pip 20.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)
получается у меня несколько версий теперь. И теперь нужно заново всё устанавливать? Как установить джанго 3 ?

Comment: я не вижу в файловой системе python 3.9. Если я обновляю его то получаю вот это apt-get install python3.9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'postgresql-plpython3-9.6' for regex 'python3.9'
postgresql-plpython3-9.6 is already the newest version (9.6.19-0+deb9u1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 110 not upgraded.
Подскажете как обновить и установить Django3?

Comment: Проверьте версии питона `python -V` и пипа `pip -V`. Удалите джангу 'pip uninstall Django'.  Затем установите джангу командой `pip install Django`. Должна поставиться последняя версия. В linux часто используется `python3` вместо 'python' и `pip3` соответственно..

Comment: @Kers и в итоге опять будет ошибка, потому что у автора назначен основным питон 3.5

Comment: Первая мысль переустановить питон  (удалив сначала старые версии). Или можно пойти другим путем и назначить алиасы к нужной версии. Или переключить версию через `sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3.9` и тд..